# Did the 1st Council of Nicea have a predecessor?

Tags: church-history, early-church, ecumenical-council, pre-nicene-fathers

Prior to the First Council of Nicea was there any single meeting or ongoing group that attempted organization of the faith and its followers in any similar way ?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Council_of_Nicaea) says that the council of Nicea was "the first effort to attain consensus in the church through an assembly representing all Christendom." Do you have a particular reason to doubt this?

Comment: It’s wikipedia.

Comment: Does the [council at Jerusalem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Council_of_Jerusalem) count (sorry for another wikipedia link)?

Comment: I don’t have any particular issue with wikipedia and I appreciate your input!   I just know that sometimes I miss what I myself have read in wikipedia or elsewhere and also there is often good info not included in wikipedia.  I appreciate any and all input!

Comment: @Conrado  also- your link about the council at jerusalem is definitely the sort of thing I had in mind thank you!  I will continue my digging from there!

Answer (score 2):

**Did the 1st Council of Nicea have a predecessor?**

In a sense yes, but not as an Ecumenical Council. To be an Ecumenical Council, the following must be observed:

> [Ecumenical Councils](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/04423f.htm) are those to which the bishops, and others entitled to vote, are convoked from the whole world (oikoumene) under the presidency of the pope or his legates, and the decrees of which, having received papal confirmation, bind all Christians. A council, Ecumenical in its convocation, may fail to secure the approbation of the whole Church or of the pope, and thus not rank in authority with Ecumenical councils. Such was the case with the Robber Synod of 449 (Latrocinium Ephesinum), the Synod of Pisa in 1409, and in part with the Councils of Constance and Basle.

Thus stated the Council of Nicaea was definitely an Ecumenical Council.

The Council of Jerusalem is considered an Apostolic Council as it was during the time when most of the Apostles were still living. It is not considered an Ecumenical Council as no convocation of bishops was asked for.

The immediate predecessors of the Ecumenical Council of Nicaea were councils or synods which were at mostly a local or provincial level only.

> In Christianity, Church councils are formal meetings of bishops and representatives of several churches who are brought together to regulate points of doctrine or discipline. The meetings may be of a single ecclesiastical community or may involve an ecclesiastical province, a nation or other civil region, or the whole Church. Some of those convoked from the Church as a whole have been recognized as ecumenical councils and are considered particularly authoritative. The first ecumenical council is that of Nicaea, called by the Emperor Constantine in 325.
>
> Pre-ecumenical councils, those earlier than AD 325, were mostly local or provincial. Some, held in the second half of the 3rd century, involved more than one province. The sui generis Council of Jerusalem was a meeting, described in the Bible in Acts 15 and possibly in Galatians 2, of the apostles and elders of the local Church in Jerusalem.
>
> In spite of lacking the authority of the decisions of ecumenical councils, the teachings and decrees of these pre-ecumenical councils are sometimes considered to be binding on the faithful in varying degrees, in particular certain councils held in Carthage and Elvira. But even the Council of Jerusalem's decisions, known as the Apostolic Decree, in particular the obligation to abstain from eating blood or what has been strangled, are not accepted by all Christian churches.
>
> **Normal pre-ecumenical councils**
>
> In times of greater toleration, Christian leaders felt sufficiently secure to hold councils governing their see or metropolitan area. None of the councils of this period gathered representatives from all the Christian churches, or even from those throughout the Roman Empire. The acts of only a few councils are preserved in surviving writings; most are known only from accounts in works of church historians and other writers. These include:
>
> - the Council of Rome of 155
> - the Council of Rome of 193
> - the Council of Ephesus of 193
> - the Council of Carthage of 251
> - the Council of Iconium of 258[13]
> - the Council of Antioch of 264
> - the Councils of Arabia of 246–247
> - the Synod of Elvira of 306
> - the Council of Carthage of 311
> - the Synod of Neo-Caesarea of c. 314
> - the Synod of Ancyra of 314
> - the Synod of Arles of 314
>
> Such councils began to appear only in the middle of the 2nd century, at first at local level, but from 175 onward they involved several communities together, with such activity particularly marked in Italy and Asia Minor. At the end of that century, it became the practice to inform other communities of the decisions taken at such assemblies. In the 3rd century, the meetings began to be held at regular intervals, a custom that appeared first in the Roman province of Africa. In the second half of that century, councils were held at Antioch that gathered representatives of Christianity throughout the Middle East, from the Black Sea to Egypt. These were a prelude to the holding of the first assembly of all bishops, the First Council of Nicaea, the event that marked the end of the period of the ancient pre-ecumenical councils.
>
> [Ancient church councils (pre-ecumenical)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_church_councils_(pre-ecumenical))

We must always keep in mind that in the year 313, the Church gained her freedom of expression in public through the ***Edict of Milan*** and as such a new more formal type of Church Council was possible and it eventually took it’s form as an Ecumenical Council in 325!

Answer (score 1):

Ken Graham is answering in the view of the Latin Church, and actually uses an unsupportable definition.  None of the Seven Ecumencial Councils recognized by both the Latins and the Orthodox as such occurred under the presidency of the Pope of Rome, nor were they presided over by legates of the Pope of Rome (though all were attended by such legates), but rather they were presided over by the Emperor or the Archbishop (later Patriarch) of Constantinople. (Usually the Emperor presided at the opening and closing session, with the Patriach presiding over the actual working sessions.)  Only one was attended by a Pope of Rome (who was there under duress).

An Orthodox view of the characteristics of an Ecumenical Council would involve being called by an Orthodox Emperor, being broadly representative of the Church, and having conclusions universally accepted by the Church.

He is correct that there were many councils which were, in a sense predecessors to Nicea.  Many heresies were dealt with, and canons established, by local councils, the conclusions of which were generally accepted by the Church.  The Council of Jerusalem (recorded in Acts 15) dealt with a Judaizing heresy.  The Council of Antioch (272) condemned the adoptionist christology of Paul of Samosata. And so forth.